# Error: Webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: nginx

My current setup is the following:

```
server {
listen 80; 
listen 443; 

root /usr/share/nginx/www;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which URLs is it redirecting to/from?

Comment: It is a lot better/cleaner to use 2 server blocks, [example](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/ssl.example.com#L4-L14).

Answer (score 0):

As AD7six mentioned, use two `server` blocks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    rewrite 301 https://$server_name$request_uri$is_args$args;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```